# Sorting by frequency in MySQL/SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there way of sorting by frequency that a value occurs? If a value appears in multiple rows, would we just use the `WHERE` clause? Is it just about making the query more specific?

As a simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
( id  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, val VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO mytable (id, val) VALUES 
(1,'one')
,(2,'prime')
,(3,'prime')
,(4,'square')
,(5,'prime')
,(6,'six')
,(7,'prime')
,(8,'cube')
,(9,'square')
;
```

We can write a simple query to return the rows

```
 SELECT t.val
      , t.id
   FROM mytable t
  ORDER BY t.val
```

But what query do we use to get the most frequently occurring values listed first? To return a result like this:

```
freq  val     id
----  ------  --
4     prime    2
4     prime    3
4     prime    5
4     prime    7
2     square   4
2     square   9
1     cube     8
1     one      1
1     six      6
```

where `freq` is the frequency (the count of the number of rows) that a value appears in the `val` column.  The value 'prime' appears in four rows, so `freq` has a value of 4.

What MySQL SELECT query would I use to return a result like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.Freq , A.val  , A.id
  FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS Freq , val , id
           FROM mytable
         GROUP BY val , id ) A
ORDER BY Freq DESC ;
```

**EDIT**:
As suggested by spencer7593, the id is defined as auto-increment in the table and hence the `GROUP BY` should not include it. Still, if that would be the case, it is not clear how the result could be as shown. I'm adding here an alternative SELECT that, supposedly, should yield the shown output:

```
SELECT B.Freq , A.val  , A.id
  FROM mytable A
INNER JOINT ( SELECT val , COUNT(*) AS Freq
                FROM mytable
              GROUP BY val) B
 ON A.val = B.val
ORDER BY B.Freq DESC ;
```

[NOTE: This was **NOT** tested!!!!]

Comment: I think `id` might a unique key. We probably want to omit `id` from the inline view query (`A`) from both the SELECT list and the GROUP BY, to get just a count of occurrences of `val`. (With `id` included, we're going to get a COUNT() of 1 for each row..) We can join inline view `A` to mytable, matching on `val` to get the individual rows associated with each count.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82afb3/1

Comment: @spencer7593, you are probably right, but the phrasing of the question may be interpreted differently. I'll update the answer to account for that possibility.